# Sass assets precompile failed on deploy with Rails 5

Tags: heroku, sass, ruby-on-rails-5

this is my first time working with sass files, its been relatively cool until i tried to deploy to heroku,i keep getting this error from my log on heroku, assets:precompile works perfectly in development but each time i try to deploy,it fails, am running on Rails 5 below is my error log

Error log

```
       Running: rake assets:precompile

       Yarn executable was not detected in the system.


4.0/gems/sass-3.5.6/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sass-3.5.6/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:161:in `visit'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sass-3.5.6/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:10:in `visit'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sass-3.5.6/lib/sass/tree/root_node.rb:36:in `css_tree'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sass-3.5.6/lib/sass/tree/root_node.rb:20:in `render'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sass-3.5.6/lib/sass/engine.rb:290:in `render'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/sass_compressor.rb:48:in `call'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/sass_compressor.rb:28:in `call'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'

remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_p
rocessors'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors
'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:134:in `load_from_unloaded'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:60:in `block in load'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:317:in `fetch_asset_from_depend
ency_cache'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:44:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in ini
tialize'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:66:in `find_asset'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:73:in `find_all_linked_assets'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:142:in `block in find'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:114:in `block (2 levels) in log
ical_paths'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:228:in `block in stat_tree'

remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:212:in `block in stat_direc
tory'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:209:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:209:in `stat_directory'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:227:in `stat_tree'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `block in logical_paths'

remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `logical_paths'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:140:in `find'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:186:in `compile'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:68:in `block (3 level
s) in define'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:147:in `with_logger'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:67:in `block (2 level
s) in define'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
remote:
remote:        Caused by:
remote:        ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (3 for 4)
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sass-3.5.6/lib/sass/script/functions.rb:752:in `rgba'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sass-3.5.6/lib/sass/script/tree/funcall.rb:155:in `block in _perform'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sass-3.5.6/lib/sass/stack.rb:108:in `block in with_function'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sass-3.5.6/lib/sass/stack.rb:135:in `with_frame'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sass-3.5.6/lib/sass/stack.rb:108:in `with_function'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sass-3.5.6/lib/sass/script/tree/funcall.rb:153:in `_perform'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sass-3.5.6/lib/sass/script/tree/node.rb:50:in `perform'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sass-3.5.6/lib/sass/script/tree/list_literal.rb:75:in `block in _perfor
m'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sass-3.5.6/lib/sass/script/tree/list_literal.rb:75:in `map'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sass-3.5.6/lib/sass/script/tree/list_literal.rb:75:in `_perform'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sass-3.5.6/lib/sass/script/tree/node.rb:50:in `perform'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sass-3.5.6/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:402:in `visit_prop'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sass-3.5.6/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sass-3.5.6/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:162:in `block in visit'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sass-3.5.6/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `block in with_base'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sass-3.5.6/lib/sass/stack.rb:135:in `with_frame'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sass-3.5.6/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `with_base'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sass-3.5.6/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:162:in `visit'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sass-3.5.6/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:444:in `block (2 levels) i
n visit_rule'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sass-3.5.6/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:444:in `map'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sass-3.5.6/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:444:in `block in visit_rul
e'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sass-3.5.6/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:183:in `with_environment'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sass-3.5.6/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:442:in `visit_rule'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sass-3.5.6/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sass-3.5.6/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:162:in `block in visit'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sass-3.5.6/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `block in with_base'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sass-3.5.6/lib/sass/stack.rb:135:in `with_frame'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sass-3.5.6/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `with_base'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sass-3.5.6/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:162:in `visit'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sass-3.5.6/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `block in visit_childre
n'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sass-3.5.6/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `map'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sass-3.5.6/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `visit_children'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sass-3.5.6/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:171:in `block in visit_chi
ldren'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sass-3.5.6/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:183:in `with_environment'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sass-3.5.6/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:170:in `visit_children'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sass-3.5.6/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `block in visit'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sass-3.5.6/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:190:in `visit_root'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sass-3.5.6/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sass-3.5.6/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:161:in `visit'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sass-3.5.6/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:10:in `visit'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sass-3.5.6/lib/sass/tree/root_node.rb:36:in `css_tree'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sass-3.5.6/lib/sass/tree/root_node.rb:20:in `render'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sass-3.5.6/lib/sass/engine.rb:290:in `render'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/sass_compressor.rb:48:in `call'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/sass_compressor.rb:28:in `call'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'

remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_p
rocessors'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors
'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:134:in `load_from_unloaded'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:60:in `block in load'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:317:in `fetch_asset_from_depend
ency_cache'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:44:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in ini
tialize'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:66:in `find_asset'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:73:in `find_all_linked_assets'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:142:in `block in find'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:114:in `block (2 levels) in log
ical_paths'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:228:in `block in stat_tree'

remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:212:in `block in stat_direc
tory'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:209:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:209:in `stat_directory'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:227:in `stat_tree'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `block in logical_paths'

remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `logical_paths'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:140:in `find'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:186:in `compile'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:68:in `block (3 level
s) in define'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:147:in `with_logger'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:67:in `block (2 level
s) in define'
remote:        /tmp/build_758c04257e9cbe8f0962e8e5ef67b23e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
4.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
remote:        Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
remote:        (See full trace by running task with --trace)
remote:  !
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to project.
remote:
```

Gemfile

```
       source 'https://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.6'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg', '>= 0.18', '< 2.0'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'

gem 'font-awesome-sass'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'

gem 'jquery-rails'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development do
    gem 'better_errors'
    gem 'letter_opener'
end

gem 'friendly_id', '~> 5.1.0' #make the urls "friendly"
gem 'cancancan' #authorize access
gem 'rolify' #assign role to user
gem 'sendgrid'
gem 'pg_search'
gem 'sitemap_generator'
gem 'fog-aws'

gem 'figaro'
gem 'devise'
gem 'devise_invitable'
gem 'simple_form'
#gem 'client_side_validations', '~> 4.2.1'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.2.0'
gem 'will_paginate-bootstrap'
#gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.1.0'
gem 'bootstrap3-datetimepicker-rails', '~> 4.17.37'

group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.7'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems RoR doesn't get as much attention on SO as before, anyways i was able to solve my problem by going through the log myself,for the sake of others am posting my answer i found a line that says

```
Caused by:
remote:        ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (3 for 4)
```

so i added null value (0) to the code rgba code on that line, i.e  rgba(12, 184, 182,0), and voila !